# getting rid of the middle line on c3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Anyone know how to get rid of this line on the picture? I wasn't able to find it on developers tool.
It appears only when I hover over one of the bars(any bar).

What I am thinking to try is:

```
 d3.selectAll("the nane of the line blah blah").filter(function(d) {
      return d === 0;
 }).remove();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it pops up on mouseover it's this you need:

```
grid: {
    focus: {
        show: false
    }
```

}

It has a link in the c3 reference documentation but no actual content or placeholder when you click on it :-p
http://c3js.org/reference.html#grid-focus-show

Answer (score 2):

That's a gridline. The c3.js solution is just:

```
grid: {
    x: {
    show: false
    }
}
```

Or, using a d3 selection, select the group they belong to (its class is "c3-xgrids") and remove that group:

```
d3.select(".c3-xgrids").remove()
```

If you want to select just one line, its class is named "c3-xgrid".

Comment: D3 way didn't work either, are you sure it is a grid because it appears when I hover over one of the bars, it should be a piece of tooltip

Comment: If it appears when you hover over the bar it's not a gridline. You should add that information in the question.